# How to add System.Windows.Forms to C# project in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-assembly, using, solution-explorer

I'm getting "The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" from "using System.Windows.Forms;". Various people on the internet say to add it through a "References" tab in Solution explorer, but for me it's not present:

[image]

[image]

How do I get the references tab to appear, or how do I otherwise get "using System.Windows.Forms" to work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#enable-net-desktop-sdk